# Will adding an external MOSFET on the switch pin of a boost converter IC increase the output capacity in terms of current?

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

So, I need a step-up DC-DC converter. I was going to use the LM2577 but I realized that the output capacity wasn't enough for my application. I was wondering if by passing the current through an external MOSFET I will be able to switch more current through the inductor and get a larger current output. Keep in mind that "go get a more powerful converter from digi-key" is not an option, where I live this is the best I can get.

My guess is that when the output of the LM2577 is pulled low, the transistor's gate should be pulled low, hence turning it on, and when the output is turned off (i.e. high impedance) it should be pulled high through R1. Any reason this wouldn't work? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzI0a6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
(sorry for the not very tidy schematic)

Comment: LM2577 has an internal switching element. So think about, what does the SWITCH node do when the switch is on, and what does it need to do to turn on your external FET?

Comment: Your basic premise - using a bigger MOSFET- is correct. You will also need to look at how the chip feedback loop is set up.

Comment: That's what I thought about, I believe it will work, though I will probably try it out on a breadboard, I wanted to know in case it works, is it a reliable way using it? Or will it be unstable and it is bound to fail?

Comment: In reply io kabZX: Ok, this increases the confidence I have that this will work well by a bit, when I finally test it I will post my results here so maybe somebody can learn a bit from this post.

Comment: Issue 1: Vsd-on of M1 is constrained by Vsg-on, leads to (unacceptably?) high dissipation of M1. Issue 2: Significant amount of power may need to be wasted on R1 to supply the drive current for M1 to switch efficiently. I don't know the availability of parts to you, but I wouldn't spend the time adapting LM2577 to do a suboptimal job.

Comment: Prueba con un LM2587 (Test with an LM2587)

Comment: Welcome to the site, does your answer have any reasoning behind it? Is there a specific reason for using a LM2587? A datasheet or app note that says external FETs are ok?

Answer (score 1):

It will work ok to a point, but the P channel MOSFET is a high-side switch; yours is on the low side.  It will turn on only until the source pulls down to the level of the gate, plus (less negative) minimum turn-on voltage.  This will cause a high Rds(ON) resulting in higher power dissipation of the FET than you would expect.  You need to connect the output to a PNP to pull up the gate of an N channel switch.